# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 error

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

So first of all, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.  I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 along side Windows 7 using the windows installer included in the download, but then when I go to restart and finish the installation, I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIQTj.jpg

I at first figured this to be a simple download error, retrying the download twice more after that (once in the browser, once in a torrent client), verifying the MD5 sum both times, with neither download working.

As stated earlier, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing with installing any operating system other than Windows, so I'd really appreciate some guidance as to if I'm doing something incorrectly.

Thanks!

EDIT: mcelog decode output

```
$ mcelog --ascii
CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 4: be00000000800400
RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff813d340b> {intel_idle+0xab/0x100}
TSC 1db9128ac4 ADDR ffffffff8136f8f0 MISC ffffffff813bf8f0
PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1396513815 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 9CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 4: be00000000800400
TSC 1db9128ac4 ADDR ffffffff8136f8f0 MISC ffffffff813bf8f0

Hardware event. This is not a software error.
CPU 0 BANK 4 TSC 1db9128ac4 
RIP !INEXACT! 10:ffffffff813d340b
MISC ffffffff813bf8f0 ADDR ffffffff8136f8f0 
TIME 1396513815 Thu Apr  3 09:30:15 2014
STATUS be00000000800400 MCGSTATUS 5
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 60
RIP: intel_idle+0xab/0x100}
PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1396513815 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 9
```

Comment: It is a hardware failure. It could be the GPU - try booting with `nomodeset`. If that does not help, check the hardware (clean the dust, re-plug cpu, memory, graphics card, try a different CPU etc.) I found the same "Exception: 5 Bank 4" error reported by a user on freedesktop, who eventually fixed it by replacing his motherboard. Does Windows 7 work ok? Interesting that the Linux kernel of the installer booted without error.

Comment: What PC is this? Laptop? It seems there is a [bug in a common wifi driver](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.commits.head/445241) which could cause a machine check exception at boot.

Comment: It's a laptop.  Windows 7 works without problem, and how would I go about booting with that condition? I honestly am entirely new to this.  Thanks.

Comment: See [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Comment: Since Windows 7 works without problem it seems this could be a software error. I noticed that your log says the kernel is tainted (has closed source drivers loaded). When you did the install, did it say that it detected any hardware that required (or recommended) close drivers? One thing you could try is to do a full install without internet connection (so it does not download any extra packages).

Comment: I tried installing it without any internet connection, and everything seems to go to plan, it installs just fine with the windows installer, I'll restart to finish the installation, it finishes without issue, until I go to do the final reboot.  Once I get there, it tells me it's unable to mount "/tmp" and "/".

Comment: Was that for a reinstall of 14.04 (that you got the error mounting / and /tmp)?

Comment: Yep, _and this is filler text_.

Comment: What Windows installer did you use?

Comment: The one included inside "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso".

Comment: What is the error? [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) ?

Comment: The only error supplied is:  

"Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

Press I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery."  

Then it's the same for /tmp if I attempt to skip it.

Comment: Can you run a hard drive checker, something that scans the whole disk for bad sectors? CPU errors, hard drive errors, it does sound like there might be a hardware issue here... is your Windows install also 64-bit? If not, could you try installing from ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso?

Comment: Is there one that you could safely recommend?

Comment: The one from the hard drive manufacturer is usually best, see the answer to [Check Bad Sectors on hard disk in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/327380/check-bad-sectors-on-hard-disk-in-windows-7) for links.

Comment: Strange, it says my drive is fine.  I tested with both SeaTools and Macrorit Drive Scanner which I found recommended by another forum.  Both came up  clean.  Something else, I tried going back a few versions of Ubuntu, and 12.04 will work just fine.  Anything after will have issues installing.

Comment: It could be a bug in the kernel. What kernel are you using in 12.04? If you take your working 12.04 and install a later kernel, does it stop working?

Comment: I honestly have no idea how I'd install a new kernel, I just used what's included in the ISO file downloaded from here.  How do I find out the kernel I'm using?

Comment: `uname -a` # The problem is that the issues you are describing are rare and hard to debug. 12.04 works. Windows works. 14.04 works until it is rebooted, then mysterious problems happen... Two things you could try: 1. on boot add parameter `modprobe.blacklist=b43` 2. Select ["Free software only"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426160/what-is-the-free-software-only-option-when-installing-ubuntu) option when you install. Or you could just use 12.04.

Comment: Sorry it's been a bit, been pretty busy the last few days.  Neither of those options worked, but I'll just use 12.04 for now.  Thanks for all the assistance.